# IPSec - Configuration best practices, performance, and realistic tradeoffs for my chosen Ciphers

Tags: encryption, vpn, aes, ipsec, cisco

I understand the term "best" is subjective but I would like to try to keep this discussion as objective as possible and get the opinion of other security professionals for my chosen cipher suite parameters.  I would like to disucss the tradeoffs of security and performance on modern hardware as of 2016.  The configuration is for site-to-sites typically involving ASA->ASA and ASA->Linux (Strongswan).  The goal of my security is protection against a corporate advesery or group of hackers.  I assume the attacker is **not** a well funded nation state and am leaning toward performance over an increase in theoretical security.

I base my research on [Strongswan's Security Recomendations](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/SecurityRecommendations)

I have come up with the following transform sets

- AES-256-XXX - I am torn between GCM and CBC mode as I believe GCM is theoretically more secure.  AES is chosen due to the fact that AES extensions are implemented in modern hardware.  Is there a large difference in performance between AES 128 v AES 256 in moden hardware?  Is there  large difference in performance between GCM and CBC mode?  I assume cipher suties like blowfish, twofish, and 3des are far slower due to non-hardware implemtations.  AES is also the "gold standard" of symetric cipher.
- SHA 256 - SHA1 is generally considered insecure hence moving to SHA256.  I don't anticipate large performance implecations between the two.
- DH Group - I am torn between this one.  I've read about performance implications of higher order DH groups.  Strongswan's recomendations are modp3072.  I have heard that modp1024 is suseptipble to weak DH but modp3072 results in worse performance by far.
- Phase 1 vs Phase 2 - In all of my IPSec confiurations I've always matched phase 1 and phase 2 parameters.  I also have also disabled PFS.  Is it suggested that Phase1 and Phase 2 match?  Also what are the implecations of performacne with regards to PRF.
- Rekeying times and DPD - I have not formed an opinion on these.

As a a bonus, Strongswan also seems to recommend the following:

- aes128gcm16-prfsha256-ecp256 (AES-GCM-128 AEAD, SHA-256 as PRF and ECDH key exchange with 256 bit key length)
- aes256gcm16-prfsha384-ecp384 (AES-GCM-256 AEAD, SHA-384 as PRF and ECDH key exchange with 384 bit key length)

Any opinions on the above cipher suites vs what I've chosen?